# Part of text not included in a div

Tags: html, css

I have an issue about some design. I want a div to be show only on mouseover from an icon, I've done this, but the content from the div is partially not included in the div.

To show you exactly how it is, here is a picture of the current thing :

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/878048issuePicture.jpg

So the div is the light orange rectangle under the arrow pointing down, but it should contain the icon and the text which is on its right (the (?) REQ and the 2 others). Those items are shown in same time as the div (on mouseover of the arrow), but they're not included in the div.

The code of those parts :

**HTML :**

```
<table class="table-center table" style="background-color:#FFFCF9">
            <thead>
               ...
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr class="changeRequestSearch">
                <td>
                    <img src="/assets/css/images/unroll-icon.png" ng-mouseenter="showSelectType()" />
                    <div class="selectType" id="selectType" ng-mouseleave="hideSelectType()">
                        <div class="nowrap">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="filterType()" id="filterReq" value="req" checked/> <img src="/assets/css/images/request-icon.png" /> REQ
                        </div>
                        <div class="nowrap">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="filterType()" id="filterEvol" value="evol" checked/> <img src="/assets/css/images/evolution-icon.png" /> EVOL
                        </div>
                        <div class="nowrap">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="filterType()" id="filterBug" value="bug" checked/> <img src="/assets/css/images/bug-icon.png" /> BUG
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                ...
```

And the **CSS** :

```
.trHover:hover {
background-color:#f5f5f5;}

.nowrap {
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.changeRequestSearch td input {
    width:100%;
}

.selectType {
    visibility:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#F5EBDE;
}
```

Here is a **JSFiddle** link, but here it does work (i've made some changes) : http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6200/

Comment: well, we need more of your css code. jsfiddle would be good

Comment: I've added some CSS. I try to make it work in jsfiddle

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle link, i've a bit edited the code for the onmouseenter which doesn't use the scope from AngularJS : http://jsfiddle.net/mainerror/D2RLR/
But here it works

Comment: I don't see any related code in jsfiddle link you posted

Comment: You're right, i've never used JSFiddle before, here's the correct link : http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6200/
But as I say, here it do work

Answer (score 0):

try to set width for the dive like

```
.selectType {
 width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. It gets resized, but the text is still outside the div :( Thanks for trying